# Trazer valores de um select com AJAX automaticamente

Tags: php, html, ajax

Comecei a usar `AJAX` há um tempinho e estou com uma dúvida. Possuo um `<select>` e estou tentando trazer o valor dele na mesma página (sem dar refresh), porém, só é exibido o valor quando eu clico no `<select>` novamente, para selecionar outra opção. Como faria para mostrar assim que eu selecionasse?

> Vamos supor que eu seleciono o `<select>` com `value="4"`, só é mostrado o "4", quando eu clico no `<select>` de novo...

**index.php:**

```
<select class="common_selector" id="ordenar_tabela">
     <option value="1">Lançamentos</option>
     <option value="2">Menor valor</option>
     <option value="3">Maior valor</option>
     <option value="4">A - Z</option>
     <option value="5">Z - A</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        var action = 'fetch_data'; 
        var ordenacao = $('#ordenar_tabela').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"verificar.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, ordenacao:ordenacao},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

});
</script>
```

**verificar.php:**

```
<?php
          $query = "SELECT * FROM produtos_estoque";
            
          // Se o usuário quiser ordenar a tabela...
          if(isset($_POST["ordenacao"])){
        
          $ordenacao = $_POST["ordenacao"];
          echo $ordenacao; //Estou exibindo essa variavel na página, para ver se vai funcionar os demais códigos abaixo...
        
          // $query .= ($ordenacao == 1) ? " ORDER BY ID_produtos DESC" : "";
          // $query .= ($ordenacao == 2) ? " ORDER BY ID_produtos DESC" : "";
          // $query .= ($ordenacao == 3) ? " ORDER BY ID_produtos DESC" : "";
          // $query .= ($ordenacao == 4) ? ' ORDER BY produto' : "";
          // $query .= ($ordenacao == 5) ? ' ORDER BY produto DESC' : "";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Vou editar mostrando a `$query`, `$('.filter_data')` apenas não foi inserido na questão.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu problema está acontecendo pois você chama a função `filter_data()` quando o `<select>` é clicado.

Veja como chamar a função ao selecionar uma nova opção, utilizando o atributo `onchange`:

```html
<select class="common_selector" id="ordenar_tabela" onchange="filter_data()">
    <option value="1">Lançamentos</option>
    <option value="2">Menor valor</option>
    <option value="3">Maior valor</option>
    <option value="4">A - Z</option>
    <option value="5">Z - A</option>
</select>
```

```js
function filter_data()
{
    var action = 'fetch_data'; 
    var ordenacao = $('#ordenar_tabela').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"verificar.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, ordenacao:ordenacao},
        success:function(data){
            $('.filter_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Outra opção, mantendo o HTML intacto e utilizando `jQuery`:

```html
<select class="common_selector" id="ordenar_tabela">
    <option value="1">Lançamentos</option>
    <option value="2">Menor valor</option>
    <option value="3">Maior valor</option>
    <option value="4">A - Z</option>
    <option value="5">Z - A</option>
</select>
```

```js
function filter_data()
{
    var action = 'fetch_data'; 
    var ordenacao = $('#ordenar_tabela').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"verificar.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, ordenacao:ordenacao},
        success:function(data){
            $('.filter_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}

$(".common_selector").change(function() {
  filter_data();
});
```

Comment: Dei uma editada na pergunta, irei usar o `value` desse `<select>` em uma condição em PHP, assim, mudando a consulta da minha página.

Comment: No `verificar.php` você está devolvendo o valor do POST, ou seja, o valor enviado. O código continua redundante. Caso deseje retornar os valores da query, é uma questão sobre SQL, não AJAX. Por favor, reformule sua questão para clarificar seu objetivo.

Comment: Teoricamente está funcionando, estou recebendo os valores e está sendo exibido corretamente. O problema, é que só está exibindo, quando eu clico no `<select>` novamente, creio que isso seja como eu estou pegando o valor com `AJAX`...

Comment: Certo. Vou reformular a resposta.

Comment: Infelizmente, não funcionou, não vi nenhuma alteração...

Comment: Utilizando o atributo `onchange`, quando você selecionar uma opção no `<select>` ele chamará a função. Seu código está utilizando o `onchange`? Confirmando, seu backend está devolvendo as informações corretamente, certo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116058/discussion-between-brhaka-and-user210741).